# Generate List with Combination of Subset of List, Java

Tags: java, list, java-8, subset, combinations

This question is to be implemented in Java.

I have a class named Competitor, with Type, Name and Power.

```
public class Competitor {
  private final int type;
  private final String name;
  private final int power;

  public Competitor(int type, String name, int power) {
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    this.power = power;
  }

  public int getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public int getPower() {
    return power;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Competitor{" + "type=" + type + ", name=" + name + ", power=" + power + '}';
  }

}
```

Now, I want to do a game, with ONE competitor by `type`, the numbers of type can be 60 (3D `arrays` or nested `for` is not a solution for me).

I want to generate all posible combination of sub Set (classified by type) of this List.

```
public class Game {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Competitor> listCompetitors = new ArrayList<>();
    listCompetitors.add(new Competitor(1, "Cat 00", 93));
    listCompetitors.add(new Competitor(1, "Cat 10", 11));
    listCompetitors.add(new Competitor(1, "Cat 23", 20));

    listCompetitors.add(new Competitor(2, "Dog 61", 54));
    listCompetitors.add(new Competitor(2, "Dog 18", 40));
    listCompetitors.add(new Competitor(2, "Dog 45", 71));
    listCompetitors.add(new Competitor(2, "Dog 30", 68));

    listCompetitors.add(new Competitor(3, "Pig 90", 90));
    listCompetitors.add(new Competitor(3, "Pig 78", 32));

    listCompetitors.add(new Competitor(4, "Cow 99", 90));

    // The type is NOT fixed number (is variable from 1 to 60)
  }
}
```

How is possible generate the combination like...

```
new Competitor(1, "Cat 00", 93)
new Competitor(2, "Dog 61", 54)
new Competitor(3, "Pig 90", 90)
new Competitor(4, "Cow 99", 90)
```

Another combination

```
new Competitor(1, "Cat 00", 93)
new Competitor(2, "Dog 61", 54)
new Competitor(3, "Pig 78", 32)
new Competitor(4, "Cow 99", 90)
```

...

The last combination

```
new Competitor(1, "Cat 23", 20)
new Competitor(2, "Dog 30", 68)
new Competitor(3, "Pig 78", 32)
new Competitor(4, "Cow 99", 90)
```

How generate sublist like proposed before?

I also raise the bet.

Taking in account the power parameter.
**What is are the `List<Competitor>` the worse(minimum sum of power) and best (maximum sum of parameter) performance?**

Comment: create lists based on types first and then generate all possible combinations as it seems like.

Comment: Looks to me like your primarily seeking an algorithm, maybe tag your question with that or move over to https://math.stackexchange.com with your question.

Comment: @Naman Thank you by your approach. I believe you have strong knowledge of stream, please put some alternative.

Answer (score 2):

First, group all elements by type, to get the lists to combine.

```
Map<Integer, List<Competitor>> map
    = listCompetitors.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Competitor::getType));
```

Then, to build the Cartesian Product, we need a helper method to create a new `List` out of an existing `List` and an additional element. Unfortunately, there’s no built-in method for that (but you might find such operations in 3rd party libraries though)

```
static <T> List<T> listWith(List<T> list, T t) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(list.size() + 1);
    result.addAll(list);
    result.add(t);
    return result;
}
```

With that, we can construct a `Stream` and collect it into a result `List`:

```
Stream<List<Competitor>> stream = Stream.of(Collections.emptyList());
for(List<Competitor> next: map.values())
    stream = stream.flatMap(list -> next.stream().map(c -> listWith(list, c)));

List<List<Competitor>> listOfListCompetitor = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Each `flatMap` step will combine the stream with another dimension.

The collection operation of `listWith` could also be done with another stream operation, e.g.

```
Stream<List<Competitor>> stream = Stream.of(Collections.emptyList());
for(List<Competitor> next: map.values())
    stream = stream.flatMap(list -> next.stream()
        .map(c -> Stream.concat(list.stream(), Stream.of(c)).collect(Collectors.toList())));

List<List<Competitor>> listOfListCompetitor = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but that’s not as intuitive, imho.